# How to get a text inside the Perl/Gtk2 TextView

Tags: perl, user-interface

I found a tutorial on how to insert a text inside the textview but i don't know how to get a text inside the textview i read the documentations of`Gtk2::TextBuffer Gtk2::TextView Gtk2::TextIter` but i can't get it so here's my sample code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Gtk2 '-init';
use Glib qw/TRUE FALSE/;

my $window=Gtk2::Window->new;
$window->signal_connect('delete_event',sub{Gtk2::main_quit;});
my $vbox=Gtk2::VBox->new();
my $textview=Gtk2::TextView->new();
my $textbuffer=$textview->get_buffer;
my $textiter1=$textbuffer->get_end_iter;
my $textiter=$textbuffer->get_start_iter;
$textbuffer->insert($textiter, "Hello");
$textview->set_buffer($textbuffer);
my $button=Gtk2::Button->new("Submit");
$button->signal_connect(clicked=>sub{
    my $rt=$textbuffer->get_text($textiter,$textiter1, 1);
    print "$rt\n";
    });
$vbox->add($textview);
$vbox->add($button);
$window->add($vbox);
$window->show_all;
Gtk2->main;`
```

thanks in advance.